# Google Trend Crawler code 429 error

Tags: python, google-api, web-crawler, google-crawlers, google-trends

I am new to python and using [unofficial `pytrends` API](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends) to crawl Google Trend. I have 2000+ keywords as DNA list and try to crawl data. When I run this code, it appears with "Google returned a response with code 429" even though I added `time.sleep(1)`. Can anyone help me with this problem?

below is my code

```
#DNA has 2000+ lists
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import time

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US,tz=360')
Data = pd.DataFrame()

#Google Trend Crawler
for i in range(DNA[i]):
    time.sleep(1)
    kw_list = [DNA[i]]
    pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='', gprop='')
    df = pd.DataFrame(pytrends.interest_over_time())

    #Setting a Google Trend Dates
    if(i==0):
        Googledate = pd.DataFrame(pytrends.interest_over_time())
        Data['Date'] = Googledate.index
        Data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    #results
    if(df.empty == True):
        Data[DNA[i]] = ""  
    else:
        df.index.name = 'Date'
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        Data[DNA[i]] = df.loc[:, DNA[i]]
Data
```

Comment: Google generally doesn't like to be crawled by "unofficial APIs".

Comment: @KlausD. Any ideas to solve this problem then? I cant seem to find an official APIs for Google Trend. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests Content-Type: text/html Retry-After:
>   3600
>
> Too Many Requests
>
> ## Too Many Requests

There is no official API for Google Trends.   Google has probably placed a limit on the number of requests coming from the same IP.

1. slow down until you figure out the limit.
2. run it on several servers allowing you to appear to come from different IP addresses.
3. stop trying to crawl Google for data they don't want to share.

Comment: Umm. This is for my individual research, so it would be difficult to use different IP addresses. 
What do you suggest for figuring out the limit? Im very new to python and the code above took me two days to write it.... :D

Comment: send 1 every minute. do that for a hour see what happens.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you! 
That would be       time.sleep(60)     right?

Comment: time.sleep(60)   # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds).

Comment: This is years after this question was posted, but dropping this here incase its useful to anybody. I wouldn't take a simple time.sleep(60) approach. 60s is usually a pretty long sleep time in scraping senses. I would look at an exponential sleep retry solution to try and keep your scrape time down where possible

Comment: google recommends using exponential backoff, most of the client libraries have it built in already